# Is greatest element not the maximal element?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My book says "The subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{N})$ consisting of all finite subsets of $\mathbf{N}$ has no maximal element".

Can someone explain this? Is it saying that there will not be a greatest element either? What about $\mathbf{N}$? Is $\phi$ the minimal element?

Comment: Look at the word *finite*.

Comment: Yes, $\emptyset$ is the minimal element. But $\Bbb N$ is not the maximal element, because it is not finite, and therefore doesn't belong to the subset in question. As for "greatest element": what do you mean by this, if not maximal element?

Comment: $\mathbf{N}$ is not a finite subset, so is not referred to in the statement.  The point is that any finite subset can be increased by adding a number it does not contain.  Also, we use Bbb N for the naturals, giving $\Bbb N$

Comment: Maximal and greatest mean the same thing.  What's the order on $P(\mathbb N)$?  Is it $\subset$?  (i.e.  $A < B \iff A\subset B$)?  If so, yes, $\emptyset$ is a minimal element and there is no greatest (As other comments noticed but I somehow completely missed,  $P(\mathbb N)$ has a maximal/greatest element of $\mathbb N$, but this is about the set of *finite* subsets.  So $\mathbb N$ is not an element of it.  .... That is to sax $\max P(\mathbb N) = \mathbb N$ but $F=$finite sets$\subsetneq P(\mathbb N)$ and $\mathbb N\not \in F$.

Comment: @fleablood: have you ever seen a different order on $P(\Bbb N)$?

Comment: Let $P$ be the maximal subset. As it is finite, it has a largest element, let $m$. But $P\cup\{m+1\}$ is a finite subset and is a proper superset of $P$, a contradiction.

Comment: @TonyK  Sure, I've seen $A< B \iff B \subset A$.  I was asking to make sure we were talking about order the same way and that we weren't be confused between the subsets *being* maximal and the subsets *having* maximal elements.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If P has the maximal subset why are we taking its largest element?

Comment: @fleablood thanks a lot!

Comment: @Drumroll: to use $m+1\notin P$.

Comment: @fleablood It's rather standard to use "maximal" to mean there's no strictly larger element and to use "greatest" to mean all the other elements are smaller. They are not equivalent in a partially ordered set. In particular, there can be several maximal elements but at most one greatest element.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That's a good point I forgot to consider.  To spell it out $A=\{\{1\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}\}$ then $\{1,3\}$ and $\{1,4\}$ are *both* maximal.  It's good that you pointed that out.